# Return Type in F-Bounded Polymorphism Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, type-erasure

I have an interface:

```
public interface Message<T extends Message<T>> {
}
```

I have a class that implements this method as

```
public class FulfilmentReleasedDomModel implements Message<FulfilmentReleasedDomModel> {}
```

And I have this method:

```
private <T extends Message<T>> Mono<T> getDomainModel(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {}
```

When I try to return an object of type `Mono<FulfilmentReleaseDomModel>` from this method, the compiler throws an error and asks me to cast it to (`Mono<T>`).

My question is, since I have bounded `T` to `extends Message`, and `FulfilmentReleasedDomModel` implements `Message<FulfilmentReleasedDomModel>`, why do I need to cast it to `Mono<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common misconception about generics is that the callee decides what the generic type is. No, the caller does.

You, as the writer of the method, don't get to decide what `T` is. By returning `Mono<FulfilmentReleasedDomModel>`, you are saying that `T` must be `FulfilmentReleasedDomModel`. But in actuality, the caller of your method will decide what `T` is. They could declare a type called `Foo` that implements `Message<Foo>` and say that `T` is `Foo`. You would need to return a `Mono<Foo>` instead.

It seems like your method should not be generic, because the callee is deciding what type to use:

```
private Mono<FulfilmentReleasedDomModel> getDomainModel(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {}
```

Alternatively, if you want to make this method more flexible, so that you can change its implementation to return something else without changing its return type, you can use generic wildcards:

```
private Mono<? extends Message> getDomainModel(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {}
```